# Handle EVT_CHAR in wxFrame or wxDialog

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cocoa, wxwidgets

As we all know, EVT_CHAR is a basic event which don't propagate to wxTopLevelWindow(wxFrame and wxDialog).

But I have a wxDialog without any wxWidgets controls on it, and need to handle user keyboard input (handle EVT_CHAR event).

I saw the wiki about catch key events globally, but it's not work on EVT_CHAR event as EVT_CHAR event need to be translated to get user input

And I have try to have wxDialog a hided children wxWindow which foward EVT_CHAR to its parent wxDialog. It works on Windows platform, and not on OSX which is my target platform.

Is there a way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I implemented what I want according to this:
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15345

In wxWidgets 3.0, wxNSView implementes NSTextInputClient protocol, which makes every widgets can handle EVT_CHAR correctly.

But EVT_CHAR still cannnot be handle by wxDialog or wxFrame, because of some call of IsUserPanel() function. So I commented some call of IsUserPanel to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to handle all keyboard entry in the dialog itself? There are two typical cases for this that I know of: either you want to handle the key presses in several different controls in the same way, or you need to handle some particular key press (e.g. `WXK_F1`) in all controls. The former can be done by [binding](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a03cc68ca201fb79c7e837919025be71a) the same event handler to several controls. The latter -- by using accelerator table with an entry for the key that you want to handle specially.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In fact, I use wxWidgets to help me porting a MFC software from Windows to OSX, in which I have my own window and control system. So I create a wxDialog as a container forwarding user input to my own control system.